# Tweepy Stream error: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to use the Tweepy python api to create a twitter search stream but I'm facing an error. Here is the code I am trying to execute and the error I'm getting ->

```
File "code.py", line 28, in <module>
    stream = Stream(auth, x, "microsoft")
__init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)
```

(Thanks for helping. Sorry, I'm a beginner)

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream

# Twitter Credentials
access_token_key = "*****"
access_token_secret = "*****"
consumer_key = "*****"
consumer_secret = "*****"

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
    """ A listener handles tweets that are the received from the stream.
    This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.
    """

    def on_data(self, data):
        print data
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token_key, access_token_secret)

    stream = Stream(auth, x, "microsoft")
    response = stream.filter(track=['microsoft'])

print response
```

Comment: are you sure error is given the way you provide, `_init_`, and not `__init__`?

Comment: it's double underscore....i was lazy to type it. sorry!

Comment: @PreritAhuja: don't type an error message; copy and paste it.

Comment: sure from now on...i was using a stupid console. sorry.

Comment: The Windows console has a copy feature; use the window menu to allow you to 'mark' to let you select, then 'copy' to copy the selected text. Terribly hidden, but that's Microsoft for you.

Answer (score 0):

Problem lies in stream intitialization line:

```
stream = Stream(auth, x, "microsoft")
```

that should be

```
stream = Stream(auth, x)
```

tracked words are passed not with constructor but in `filter` method.

Comment: I get this error  ---------- File ".\twittersearch_v3.py", line 30, in <module>
   response = stream.filter(track=['microsoft'])
 File "build\bdist.win32\egg\tweepy\streaming.py", line 242, in filter
 File "build\bdist.win32\egg\tweepy\streaming.py", line 181, in _start
 File "build\bdist.win32\egg\tweepy\streaming.py", line 120, in _run
ttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'on_error'

Comment: @PreritAhuja do you get http 307 or AtrributeError? If latter, you probably left "microsoft" instead of x. And if first, then your tweepy might be too old, please check that tweepy version is older than 2.0

Comment: this is what I'm using
{
x = StdOutListener()
stream = Stream(auth, x)
response = stream.filter(track=['microsoft'])
print response
}
and just getting "307". It doesn't say anything else and I'm using tweepy 2.1

Answer (score 0):

`Stream()` only takes 2 arguments (plus `self` for bound methods):

```
stream = Stream(auth, x)
stream.filter(track=['microsoft'])
```

See the [streaming example](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/examples/streaming.py) given by the Tweepy project.

The 307 redirect should probably be handled as not an error; you can tell Tweepy to continue by returning `True` from the `on_error` handler:

```
def on_error(self, status):
    print status
    if status == 307:
        return True
```